# Golang chmod files and directories recursively

Tags: linux, go, permissions, chmod

I'm trying to use [`WalkDir`](https://godocs.io/path/filepath#WalkDir) with `Chmod` to recursively change the permission of a directory and its files and subdirectories. Somehow it does just change the first file or directory of the given path and stops afterwards. Can someone spot the mistake? `getFileMode` just converts the string "755" in `os.FileMode(0755)` and returns it.

```golang
func ChmodRec(path string, di fs.DirEntry, err error) error {
    fileMode, err2 := getFileMode(os.Getenv("CHMOD_MODE"))
    if err2 != nil {
        log.Fatal("Could not set file mode for chmodding", path)
        panic(err)
    }

    err2 = os.Chmod(path, fileMode)
    if err2 != nil {
        fmt.Println("Could not chmod", path)
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Changing mode of", path)
    return nil
}

func ChmodRecursive(path string, mode string) {
    os.Setenv("CHMOD_MODE", mode)
    err := filepath.WalkDir(path, ChmodRec)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Could not chmod recursively ", path)
        panic(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    path := "bla/test/"
    mode := "755"
    ChmodRecursive(path, mode)
}
```

Comment: How does this even build without you adding parameters to `ChmodRec` in `err := filepath.WalkDir(path, ChmodRec)`? Not that I'm an expert in go ...

Comment: @tink functions are first class citizen in GO. You can send the function as another function argument, and that second function can invoke it with parameters.

Comment: If I implement `getFileMode` your code runs fine for me; I'd guess that your issue is in `getFileMode` (did you remember that `755` is octal not decimal?). Following the advice in the answer from @DmitryHarnitski will probably result in a 'permission denied' error. [Minimal, *reproducible*, examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not check `err` argument in `ChmodRec`. This is an extract from official documentation:

> WalkDir calls the function with a non-nil err argument in two cases.
>
> First, if the initial fs.Stat on the root directory fails, WalkDir
> calls the function with path set to root, d set to nil, and err set to
> the error from fs.Stat.
>
> Second, if a directory's ReadDir method fails, WalkDir calls the
> function with path set to the directory's path, d set to an
> fs.DirEntry describing the directory, and err set to the error from
> ReadDir. In this second case, the function is called twice with the
> path of the directory: the first call is before the directory read is
> attempted and has err set to nil, giving the function a chance to
> return SkipDir and avoid the ReadDir entirely. The second call is
> after a failed ReadDir and reports the error from ReadDir. (If ReadDir
> succeeds, there is no second call.)

Add this code to the beginning of the function. It can give you a hint:

```
func ChmodRec(path string, di fs.DirEntry, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
```

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem! My path that I was given to ChmodRec could not be found with lstat, thats why it was throwing an error that I couldn't see without that error checking. I tried to filepath.join the path inside the chmodrec function but I have to do it before that because WalkDir is already checking the given path before stepping into the function.